# Add dynamic divs around 6 image urls using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I need help to render 6 images retrieved from mysql database in mvc razor view.  Images 1 and 6 are put in their separate divs called "item". Images 2,3,4 and 5 are all put in one div called "item -item-small"  Below is the original  rendering:

```
<div class="owl-photos">

    <a href="post.html" class="item-photo">
      <img src="images/photos/image-1.jpg" alt="" />image1
    </a>

    <a href="post.html" class="item-photo">
      <img src="images/photos/image-2.jpg" alt="" />image2
    </a>

    <a href="post.html" class="item-photo">
      <img src="images/photos/image-3.jpg" alt="" />image3
    </a>
    <a href="post.html" class="item-photo">
      <img src="images/photos/image-4.jpg" alt="" />image4
    </a>
    <a href="post.html" class="item-photo">
      <img src="images/photos/image-5.jpg" alt="" />image5
    </a>

    <a href="post.html" class="item-photo">
      <img src="images/photos/image-6.jpg" alt="" />image6
    </a>

  </div>
```

Below is what I want to achieve:

```
<div class ="owl-photos">

<div class="item">  
<a href="post.html" class="item-photo">
<img src="images/photos/image-1.jpg" alt="" />image1
</a>
</div>


<div class="item item-small">
<a href="post.html" class="item-photo">
<img src="images/photos/image-2.jpg" alt="" />image2
</a>
<a href="post.html" class="item-photo">
<img src="images/photos/image-3.jpg" alt="" />image3
</a>
<a href="post.html" class="item-photo">
<img src="images/photos/image-4.jpg" alt="" />image4
</a>
<a href="post.html" class="item-photo">
<img src="images/photos/image-5.jpg" alt="" />image5
</a>
</div>


<div class="item">
<a href="post.html" class="item-photo">
<img src="images/photos/image-6.jpg" alt="" />image6
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Any help in using JQuery will be appreciated I do not know how to start this.  I can add classes to first element but this is a big challenge

Attempted with the code below:

```
$(".owl-photos>div:nth-child(1n)").before("<div class="item">");
$(".owl-photos>div:nth-child(1n)").after("</div><div class="item item-small">");
$(".owl-photos>div:nth-child(1n)").after("<div class="item item-small">");
$(".owl-photos>div:nth-child(5n)").after("</div><div class="item ">");
$(".owl-photos>div:nth-child(6n)").after("</div>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function () {
  var $result = $('<div class="owl-photos"></div>');

  var length = $('.owl-photos a').length;

    $('.owl-photos a').each(function (key, item) {
    if (key == 0 || key == length - 1) {
      var $div = $('<div class="item"></div>').append(item);
      $result.append($div);
    } else {
      var $small = $result.find('.item-small');
      console.log($small);
      if (!$small.length) {
        var $div = $('<div class="item item-small"></div>').append(item);
        $result.append($div);
      } else {
        $small.append(item);
      }
    }
  });

  $('.owl-photos').html($result.html());
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/atw4gwrr/

Answer (score 0):

You can create elements with JavaScript, append the specific elements to them, then place the new elements into `.owl-photos`. By appending the `<a>` elements to the newly made `<div>`s they are moved from their previous place, that's why you don't see them duplicate.

Below, I get the list of childs, then group them as such:

- The `.first()` child is placed in a `<div class="item">`, then appended
- The `:not(:first-child)` and `:not(:last-child)` elements are placed in `<div class="item item-small">`, then appended
- The `.last()` child is placed in a `<div class="item">`, then appended

```js
$(function(){
  var $photos = $('.owl-photos'),
      $childs = $photos.children(),
      $itemWrapper = $(document.createElement('div')).attr('class','item'),
      $itemSmallWrapper = $(document.createElement('div')).attr('class','item item-small');
  $photos.append(
    $itemWrapper.clone().append($childs.first()),
    $itemSmallWrapper.clone().append($childs.filter(':not(:first-child), :not(:last-child)')),
    $itemWrapper.clone().append($childs.last())
  );
})
```

```css
.item { border: 3px solid green }
.item.item-small { border: 3px solid blue }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="owl-photos">
    <a href="post.html" class="item-photo">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=1" alt="" />image1
    </a>
    <a href="post.html" class="item-photo">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=2" alt="" />image2
    </a>
    <a href="post.html" class="item-photo">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=3" alt="" />image3
    </a>
    <a href="post.html" class="item-photo">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=4" alt="" />image4
    </a>
    <a href="post.html" class="item-photo">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=5" alt="" />image5
    </a>
    <a href="post.html" class="item-photo">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=6" alt="" />image6
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: I can see your solution also works very well.  I am yet to test it in my application